# Last matching symbol in Regex

Tags: python, regex

I couldn't find a more descriptive title, but here there is an example:

```
import re
m = re.search(r"\((?P<remixer>.+) (Remix)\)", "Title (Menda Remix)")
m.group("remixer") # returns 'Menda' OK
m = re.search(r"\((?P<remixer>.+) (Remix)\)", "Title (Blabla) (Menda Remix)")
m.group("remixer") # returns 'Blabla) (Menda' FAIL
```

This regex finds the first parenthesis, and I would like to match the last parenthesis for always getting 'Menda'. I've made a workaround to this using extra functions, but I would like a cleaner and a more consistent way using the same regex.

Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
re.search(r"\((?P<remixer>[^)]+) (Remix)\)", "Title (Blabla) (Menda Remix)")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `[^()]+` instead of `.+` to not to match the parenthesis.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably do this:

```
m = re.search(r".*\((?P<remixer>.+) (Remix)\)", "Title (Blabla) (Menda Remix)")
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a `$` to the end of the pattern and you're done :)

```
import re
m = re.search(r"\((?P<remixer>[^)]+) (Remix)\)$", "Title (Menda Remix)")
print m.group("remixer") # returns 'Menda' OK
m = re.search(r"\((?P<remixer>[^)]+) (Remix)\)$", "Title (Blabla) (Menda Remix)")
print m.group("remixer") # returns 'Blabla) (Menda' FAIL
```

PS: I've also changed the `.+` to `[^)]+` so you won't match any `)` in the process.

Comment: the reason it matches has nothing whatsoever to do with `$` and all with the change to character class

Comment: If there would be more matches than it would still only get the last match so it's still a useful addition